# YouTube black border bug introduced

Tags: youtube-api

I think YouTube deployed an update last night which has broken responsive YouTube embeds. I found and added to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119210595) in the tracker, however the issue tracker as a whole doesn't seem to be in active use by Google. It's full of unmoderated spam and I've been back over a month and not a single issue had changed status or had an assignment.

1. Is there a way to submit a bug report that will actually be seen?
2. Is anyone else seeing this issue?
3. Has anyone found an easy fix? I'd prefer not have have to fix this with JS if I can avoid it.

Comment: I added the issue report. I noticed that it seems to be the case in multiple sites. Some mention that it was introduced this week, though I'm not 100% sure. 

Hoping this will be fixed asap as I don't see any way of creating a responsive youtube embed video without introducing this new black border bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able use Bootstrap 4, you can use its iframe responsive (there's no issue with black borders):

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[Full doc B4 responsive iframe](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/embed/)

Comment: I believe this issue got fixed today which is why you're no longer seeing the problem. Bootstrap was not immune to the problem.

Comment: @Hawxby watched this problem on this page from report https://www.csselectronics.com/screen/overview